# Groovy enum: switch statement throws error before running relating to static

Tags: groovy, enums

The following code can be compiled fine in Intellij, but when trying to use Groovy as a script, it throws an error even before running. 
I can't find out the crack, since everything is static actually?

```
public enum OutputType {
        ABC,
        DEF,
        GHI
    }
    //Just initializing here
        public static OutputType output=OutputType.ABC;



    public static void run() {

        switch (output){
            case ABC:
                runABC();
                break;

            case DEF:
                runDEF();
                break;

            case GHI:
                runGHI();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

The error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 50: Apparent variable 'ABC' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'ABC' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 50, column 18.
               case ABC:
                    ^

Script1.groovy: 54: Apparent variable 'DEF' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'DEF' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 54, column 18.
               case DEF:
                    ^

Script1.groovy: 58: Apparent variable 'GHI' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'GHI' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 58, column 18.
               case GHI:
```

Comment: in groovy **script** you can't define static variables. however you could do it in class

Comment: Do your switch cases need to be `OutputType.DEF` and so on (vs just `case(DEF)`?

Comment: Well, for me no, but I'm doing it for someone else who insists on that. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried removing the static stuff from your script and adding enum class name in your cases?

```
    switch (output){
        case OutputType.ABC:
            runABC();
            break;

        case OutputType.DEF:
            runDEF();
            break;

        case OutputType.GHI:
            runGHI();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I retried with deleting all static statements before. 
Got a new error now. Unfortunately I had to wipe the classname:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: OutputType for class: XXXXXXXXXXX.tempscripts.Script1
```

Since this this another issue I marked the answer above as correct.
Thank you!

Comment: As well I had to import the Type before the class. Weird, but found the solution in a book: https://books.google.de/books?id=of0VBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=groovy+MissingPropertyException+enum&source=bl&ots=4DLBwFEpc4&sig=ACfU3U06a2e4dnfkYTaZoiHzNuYq96BMoA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-nouwn8XiAhXNLFAKHRyOBHQQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=groovy%20MissingPropertyException%20enum&f=false